# Mail sent using PHP form showing garbled Japanese text

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmailer

I've searched heaps on the net but nothing seems to make my code work. My php code results in emails looking like this:

叹涟: Bob
メッセ〖ジ: 銇撱倱銇仭銇��

They should look like this (with Japanese characters):

名前: Bob
メッセージ: こんいちは。

It works fine when entering English characters into the fields:

名前: Chris
メッセージ: Hello, this is a test message.

Here's the code. The website page itself is encoded as euc-jp. The email subject shows without problems. The text is garbled in my Mac mail app, and on my android devices (gmail app, android mail app). Maybe it's a problem with the htmlspecialchars function. I don't know enough about php to fix it. Please help me!

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));


$to = "test@topenglishkanazawa.com\r\n";
$email_subject = "お問い合わせ\r\n";
$email_body = "名前: $name<br><br>メッセージ: $message\r\n";
$headers = "From: webform@topenglishkanazawa.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=euc-jp\r\n";
mail($to,'=?euc-jp?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=',$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Updated code:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
$to = 'test@topenglishkanazawa.com';
$email_subject = "お問い合わせ";
$email_body = "名前: $name\n\n"."メッセージ: $message";
$headers = "From: webform@topenglishkanazawa.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: Is your script actually written in euc-jp, and not something incompatible like UTF-8?

Comment: If you look at the php manual, `htmlspecialchars()` third arguments takes the encoding. It defaults to utf-8. Many functions/libraries if not all default to utf-8 in php. Example fgetcsv,...

Comment: Yes, the script is euc-jp. So if I put the argument in, it should look like this right? (see above)

Comment: Now nothing shows up for the variables $name and $message...

Comment: check the file's encoding. It should also be saved as UTF-8 if it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks. I set the file encoding to UTF-8 and it seems to be working on my Mac email client. However, when viewed on android I still see a bunch of ???????? and diamonds with question marks inside...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but your code works perfectly fine for me; 
I tried with:

```
<?php
$_POST['name']= 'Bob';
$name = $_POST['name'];

$_POST['email']= 'mailforbob@gmail.com';
$_POST['message']= ' こんいちは';
echo $_POST['name'];

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
empty($_POST['email'])       ||
empty($_POST['message']) ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'],'EUC-JP'));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'],'EUC-JP'));
$to = 'myemail@myemail.com';
$email_subject = "お問い合わせ";
$email_body = "名前: $name\n\n"."メッセージ: $message";
$headers = "From: webform@topenglishkanazawa.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo 'email sent';
return true;   
?>
```

I suggest you to  check your browser or computer language setting ;)

Comment: Thanks for testing it! I updated the code above to the one I'm currently using. File encoding is set to UTF-8, embedded page charset is set to euc-jp. No problems when receiving the email on the mail app on Mac. However, when viewing on Android it is garbled... What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I should also add, all other Japanese mails work fine on android. It's only the ones sent using the code above that show up garbled.

Comment: Can you try using shift-JIS instead of euc-jp? and <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=SHIFT-JIS"> on your form ;)

Comment: Why do you suggest putting <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=SHIFT-JIS"> in my form? The form is php. This is not php, right?

Comment: I've now tried putting everything in UTF-8, which should work fine theoretically. But get the same result. Just ????????? and black diamonds. Please tell me your email address and I will give you the test page to try it for yourself.

Comment: When I changed to "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($email_subject)."?=" in the bottom line, the subject now displays properly. I don't understand why this needs to be added if everything is set to utf-8 already

Comment: It must be a problem with android. I've tried everything, and it works fine in the mac mail app and on the server webmail app. :(

Comment: because I copied the source of your 問い合わせ from, changed the euc-jp to UTF-8 and it worked.

Comment: additionally I found this blog written by Japanese guy: take this as reference. [https://www.bricoleur.co.jp/blog/archives/3480]

Answer (score 1):

This function will fix your issue:

```
$body_user = mb_convert_encoding($body_user, "UTF-8","UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried inserting this into the php file with no luck. Is there anywhere special I need to insert it?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and solved by putting this on the top of my php file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<html>
<head>
```

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); 
Will encode all the form characters to be the ones you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add UTF-8 as the encoding for your email within the headers. I find using an array helps with readability, but it's up to you:

```
$headers = array(
  'From' => $from_address,
  'Reply-To' => $reply_address,
  'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
);
$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Make sure it's `text/plain` not `text/html` if you want any line feeds using `\r\n` to stay in tact once you've changed to UTF-8.

And double-check that the form submitting the `POST` data is doing so in UTF-8 format.